# how do i fetch tweets from a certain area?

Tags: python, validation, twitter, geocoding

I have a problem with the function search_tweets as soon as I introduce the parameter geocode and I can't tell why I cannot find any tweet but I do get data when i remove that parameter though. what should i do ?
here is the portion of code i used to test the function with

```
new_tweets = api.search_tweets(q=any,geocode='latitude = 36.7762 longitude = 3.05997' ,count=20)
if new_tweets != '':  
  for tw in new_tweets:
    print(tw.text)
  else:
      print('no tweets found')`
```

Comment: I assume this is using Tweepy? Which version?

Comment: Only a small number of Tweets have geodata information, and the search API by default only covers 7 days, so it might be legitimate that there are no results.

Comment: I just started discovering the API so it's the last version of tweepy, i don't understand the second comment could you clarify please

Comment: If no Tweets with geo information have been posted that match the search terms within the past 7 days then you will get no results. Only a small percentage of Tweets overall have geo information attached to them. Since you did not include the complete code / specify that this was Tweepy then many developers would not have been able to reproduce your issue, which is why I asked to confirm that this is Tweepy.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering, this was really helpful

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.